# Initialize SubView and exception

Tags: ios

I have a UICollectionView Cell that try to initialize a custom subview but giving me error.

```
     //In Init  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    DetailSubView *view=[[DetailSubView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.contentView=view;---> ERROR

    //.h file
    @property   (strong, nonatomic) DetailSubView          *contentView;
```

Error

[DetailCustomCell setContentView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe48a090

Comment: What method is this under?

Comment: - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `contentView` property of a cell is read-only. To customize the cells content view, add subviews to it.